# Axios post stalled in Chrome (CORS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, axios, nanoexpress

I am converting a code that connected AWS Lambda to nanoexpress. My VueJS frontend was not passing data correctly so I started to do changes and now I cannot reach the backend at all and I have no idea why.

The backend is trivial:

```
const nanoexpress = require('nanoexpress');
const app = nanoexpress();
app.post('/v1/authorizeUser', async (req) => {
    console.log(req);
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log(email);
    return { status: 'Ok', body: req.body };
});   
app.listen(3000).then(r => console.log('started'));
```

This is the original store.js code. I am able to send the request from Vue app in Chrome but it is not parsed correctly. Probably because of missing or incorrect content type

```
const axiosResponse = await axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/authorizeUser`, JSON.stringify({
  email: payload.email,
  password: payload.password,
}));
```

and the server log:

```
body: [Object: null prototype] {
 '{"email":"literak@seznam.cz","password":"centrum"}': ''
}
undefined
```

[image]

When I added Axios options, the chrome shows an error for this request but there is nothing on server.

```
 const options = {
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
 };
 const axiosResponse = await axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/authorizeUser`, JSON.stringify({
    email: payload.email,
    password: payload.password,
 }), options);
```

Chrome request looks strange, there is no response section, request headers are very different and I can see in the Timing tab, that the request stalled.

[image]

If I remove stringify function, it behaves the same:

```
const axiosResponse = await axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/authorizeUser`, {
   email: payload.email,
   password: payload.password,
}, options);
```

And same trouble without stringify and custom options:

```
const axiosResponse = await axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/authorizeUser`, {
   email: payload.email,
   password: payload.password,
}, options);
```

Only the first variant with stringify and without options reaches the server. I use Postman the request is processed by the server.

[image]

logs:

```
  body: { email: 'literak@seznam.cz', password: 'centrum' }
}
literak@seznam.cz
```

Axios is the latest 0.19.2 version. Chrome is up to date as well. I have no idea why the other combinations do not reach the server. It looks like Chrome received a correct request. What can be wrong? It drives me crazy.

Update: console

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:83)
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like a failing CORS preflight. Recent versions of Chrome don't show the OPTIONS request in the Network tab but you should still get a clear error message in the console. Firefox will show the OPTIONS request so you may have more luck there.

Comment: If your backend is on different domain/port than frontend, it can be blocked due to CORS, if not explicitly allowed.

Comment: I have updated question with the console logs. The backend is not configured to check CORS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `nanoexpress` but if it's like Express you'll need a 404 handler, otherwise unhandled requests will hang. The browser will be sending a CORS preflight OPTIONS request and currently you aren't handling it.

Comment: If it was CORS, why the first variant does reach the server?

Comment: The first variant still uses CORS (you can see that in the request headers) but it doesn't require a preflight because it is using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for its `Content-Type`. The second request uses `application/json`, which does trigger a preflight.

Comment: Thanks, I try to change the backend. The first attempt did not detect OPTIONS call and error handler was not invoked. At least I have a direction now.

Comment: Origin is checked at client (not backend) by browser for security reasons.

Comment: This will be the trouble, please provide an answer so I can accept it. I have submitted an issue to nanoexpress: https://github.com/nanoexpress/nanoexpress/issues/83.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS in nanoexpress is apparently [known bug](https://nanoexpress.js.org/testing/known-bugs#cors-per-route-bug):

```
const corsPerRoute = cors();
app.options('/my-route', corsPerRoute, () => {});

app.get('/my-route', corsPerRoute, (req, res) => {
  res.send('this route protected by your cors per-route config');
});
```